# Python code to extract last 16 characters from 32 characters

Tags: python, python-2.7, bitwise-operators, xor

I am trying to extract the last 16 characters of this hexadecimal value and xor it with the first 16 bits of the same 32 characters or 128-bit value using python code. I am not sure what function to be used here. I tried taking this as a string divide the length by half and then xor the two values. Is there a possibly easy way to find the extract these bits and xor them?

For instance my 32 bit value is : `ee230c06cac0aa070be45290b1cb11ee`

My last 16 bit value should be : `0be45290b1cb11ee`; and 
my first 16 bit value should be: `ee230c06cac0aa07`

Comment: Are you looking for binary (bitwise) OR and AND operations?

Comment: How `ee230c06cac0aa070be45290b1cb11ee` is 32 bit 

Comment: Those are 128bit and 64 bit values...

Comment: As others have mentioned, those are 128 bits or 32 *characters*. If you have them as a simple string, try using `value[16:]` and `value[:16]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Note**: based on your example you work with a 128-bit number, and you want to split it into two 64-bit numbers. The below stated techniques can however easily be modified for any number of bits.

In order to obtain the **lowest 16 bits, you can mask** with `0xffff`, like:

```
lowest_16 = number & 0xffff
```

Now in order to get the **highest 16 bits, you can shift** (and probably better mask as well, since in [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x) numbers have arbitrary length):

```
highest_16 = (number  >> 16 ) & 0xffff
#                     ^       ^ masking out higher bits
#                     | bitwise shift 16 position to the right
```

So the result is:

```
result = ((number >> 16 ) & 0xffff) ^ (number & 0xffff)
#                                   ^ bitwise xor operation
```

Note that you can **mask after the xor** (saving one bitwise and operation) since by masking, you set these higher values to zero anyway. So you can make it more efficient like:

```
result = ( (number >> 16 ) ^ number) & 0xffff
```

In case you want to work with **128-bit numbers**, you can use:

```
result_128 = ( (number >> 64 ) ^ number) & 0xffffffffffffffff
#                                          ^ 64-bit mask
```

For example:

```
>>> number = 0xee230c06cac0aa070be45290b1cb11ee
>>> hex(( (number >> 64 ) ^ number) & 0xffffffffffffffff) # xor-ing
'0xe5c75e967b0bbbe9'
>>> hex(number >> 64) # highest bits
'0xee230c06cac0aa07'
>>> hex(number & 0xffffffffffffffff) # lowest bits
'0xbe45290b1cb11ee'
```

Comment: When are trying to write it in a function I am getting a Type Error below:             
    **TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for >>: 'str' and 'int'**
The code I have written is : **result_128 = ( (value >> 64 ) ^ value) & 0xffffffffffffffff** . Could you tell me how to get this corrected.

Comment: Where do you see a function?

Comment: I didn't get you. I was writing a program to implement this as a part of the code and here is the [link] (https://github.com/haritha28/SSOC/blob/master/assignments/reverse/u4cse14030/validate.py)

Comment: @harithaharikumar: you first need to convert the hexadecimal **string** to an integer, with `int(value,16)`...

Comment: I am getting the answer but I am getting an extra L at the end of the answer which I am not sure why it is coming: 0xe5c75e967b0bbbe9L

Comment: @harithaharikumar: use `hex(..).rstrip('L')` to remove the tailing `L`. You can also use `hex(..).rstrip('L').lstrip('0x')` to remove the leading `0x...`.